# How to decode Cyrillic characters without touching html tags

Tags: php, html-entities

I am fetching some content from remote sources and some of the them output Cyrillic characters like this:

```
&#1065;&#1077;&#1088;&#1082;&#1072;&#1090;&#1072;
```

Browsers can read this just fine, but there are issues with some programs. After running this through PHP's [html_entity_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) I can get the correct characters and the text looks like this:

```
Щерката
```

The problem is that [html_entity_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) also decodes any HTML tags inside the string and I don't want them to be touched.

Is there any way of doing this without affecting the HTML tags?

Comment: You could do this by replacing `&lt;` and `&gt;` to temporary strings, then do the entity decode, then replace back.

Comment: I don't get it. If you have a string like `&#1065;&lt;b&gt;`, what's the problem with decoding the `<b>` together with the character?

Comment: Because sometimes I have a mix with real HTML tags which should be passed as tags to the browser, and some which are not real, like nicknames enclosed in < and > They should be kept encoded in the final output. Mikes comment sounds reasonable though.

Answer (score 0):

(Double)encode the `<` and `>` sequences first with a simple `str_replace()` and then do the decode

Answer (score 0):

```
var_dump(htmlspecialchars(html_entity_decode('&#1065;&lt;b&gt;')));
```

Gives me:

```
string(11) "Щ&lt;b&gt;"
```